# Solve coupled set of second order nonlinear differential equations using MatLab

Tags: matlab

I'm basically trying to model the motion of a compound double pendulum, the lagrange equations produce this pair of coupled differential equations: [Equations of motion for a compound pendulum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEp8d.png).

I wish to apply ode45 to model the behavior over time. I understand that they need to be reduced into 4 first order equations, but I'm baffled over the syntax/rearrangement that may or may not be required due to the coupling.

Comment: can you post some code you have tried so far?

Comment: You now have two variables, q1 and q2. Since the equations are second-order, you need to introduce new variables that are identical to the first derivatives of these two variables; let's call them q3 and q4. You introduce equations \dot q1 = q3, \dot q2 = q4, substitute \dot q1 and \dot q2 by q3 and q4 in the two equations you have, and solve them for \dot q3 and \dot q4. You then have a system of first-order differential equations in four variables.